# Change name of the columns in Datagridview when only a few are selected

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, datagridview

I am looking to change the names of my columns when only a few are selected.  
 Here is my code, that is working to select the columns. 

 Now, How can I change their name?

```
        OleDbDataAdapter myadapt = new OleDbDataAdapter(mycommand);
        myadapt.Fill(myset, "Properties");
        DataTable tbSearchResult = myset.Tables["Properties"];
        DataTable tbTemp = new DataTable();

        tbTemp = tbSearchResult.DefaultView.ToTable(true, "DescriptionCities", "DescriptionSurface", "DescriptionBathroom", "DescriptionPrices", "DescriptionRooms", "DescriptionType");

        GridView1.DataSource = tbSearchResult;
        GridView1.DataBind();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might do the trick for you

```
string[] selectedColumns = new[] { "DescriptionCities", "DescriptionSurface", "DescriptionBathroom", "DescriptionPrices", "DescriptionRooms", "DescriptionType" };
DataTable dt= new DataView(tbSearchResult).ToTable(false, selectedColumns);
```

and to change the name of the columns you can do

```
dt.Columns["DescriptionCities"].ColumnName = "Cities";
```

Comment: select the columns is working, How can I change the name of the columns?

Comment: Happy to help. You can mark this as answer. :) This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution

Comment: I will! I can only do it in 4mn

Answer (score 0):

You can change the sql select statement to select only the columns you want and give the header name as below

```
select DescriptionCities as Cities, DescriptionSurface as [Description Surface] from YourTable
```